# Modifying file properties/metadata

Tags: c#, pinvoke, file-attributes, file-properties

I can get a file's properties/metadata by calling `Shell32.Folder.GetDetailsOf`, but I can't seem to figure out how to modify those attributes. The properties I'm referring to are the "extended details" like Camera model and Camera name for image files.

Comment: Can't do it for images, unfortunately, as EXIF data is at the start of the binary for the image and takes up a fixed amount of space.

Comment: `Folder.GetDetailsOf` is a vba method, not a .NET one. You tagged the question C#. Please clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IF you are indeed using C# then you must do some Interop/PInvoke to call that method since that is Shell method...

To get+set EXIF information you can use the [`Image`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.setpropertyitem.aspx) class (though not optimal), for the standard attributes you can use the [`FileInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) class.

A very good class for doing EXIF related stuff including source can be found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/exiftagcol.aspx).

Comment: The class in your last link is certainly very helpful in dealing with, but it doesn't look like it can set EXIF information at the moment. Also, why is the `Image` class not optimal for setting EXIF?

Comment: AFAIK using `Image` class can result in rewriting the image file which can incurr depending on the file format etc. a possible slight loss in quality... another point is that it loads the image into memory which can be a performance issue if you only want to deal with the EXIF data...

Comment: It looks like using `Image` is my only choice at this moment. I can't seem to find any other libraries or classes that can modify EXIF information.

Comment: there are several commercial ones available if that is an option I could give you some links...